# How to append a multindex to my dataframe in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I would like to add a multiindex to my dataframe. 
I looked into the pandas.pydata `[documentation][1]` without any luck.

My dataframe looks like this where the Name is the index, and the date include the speed for the vessels:

```
                     27/02/2020
Name                      
MAERSK EDMONTON       19.1
MAERSK EMDEN           0.0
MAERSK ENPING          0.0
MAERSK ESSEN           0.0
MAGLEBY MAERSK         0.1
METTE MAERSK          17.7
MSC AMBITION           0.0
MSC ARIANE            17.4
MSC CAMILLE            0.0
```

The desired output would look like this. The vessels belong to a given alliance, in this case 2M Alliance.

```
2M_Alliance
                     27/02/2020
Name                      
MAERSK EDMONTON       19.1
MAERSK EMDEN           0.0
MAERSK ENPING          0.0
MAERSK ESSEN           0.0
MAGLEBY MAERSK         0.1
METTE MAERSK          17.7
MSC AMBITION           0.0
MSC ARIANE            17.4
MSC CAMILLE            0.0
```

Here's what I've got so far.

```py
df_alli = df[df.Name.isin(["MAERSK EMDEN", "METTE MAERSK", "MAGLEBY MAERSK", "MSC ARIANE", "MAERSK EDMONTON", "MAERSK ENPING", "MSC AMBITION", "MSC CAMILLE", "MAERSK ESSEN"])]
df_name = pd.DataFrame()

df_name["Name"] = df_alli["Name"]
df_name[date] = df_alli[date]

#df_name = df_name.set_index("Name")

arrys = [["2M_Alliance"], df_name["Name"]]
s = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(arrys, names=["Alliance", "Name"])
s = pd.Series(df_name[date], index=s)
s = pd.DataFrame(s)
print(s)
```

The output looks fine, but the NaN are not filled out, and I'm not sure why. 
Outputs:

```
                            27/02/2020
Alliance    Name                      
2M_Alliance MAERSK EDMONTON        NaN
            MAERSK EMDEN           NaN
            MAERSK ENPING          NaN
            MAERSK ESSEN           NaN
            MAGLEBY MAERSK         NaN
            METTE MAERSK           NaN
            MSC AMBITION           NaN
            MSC ARIANE             NaN
            MSC CAMILLE            NaN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create new column by [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) and then use [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
df_name = df_alli.assign(Alliance = '2M_Alliance').set_index(['Alliance','Name'])
print (df_name)
                             27/02/2020
Alliance    Name                       
2M_Alliance MAERSK EDMONTON        19.1
            MAERSK EMDEN            0.0
            MAERSK ENPING           0.0
            MAERSK ESSEN            0.0
            MAGLEBY MAERSK          0.1
            METTE MAERSK           17.7
            MSC AMBITION            0.0
            MSC ARIANE             17.4
            MSC CAMILLE             0.0
```